# iepngfix.htc and jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict, iepngfix

I use iepngfix.htc for png in IE6 and jQuery(noConflict mode).
iepngfix.htc doesn't work with jQuery, which means png transparency doesn't work.
It's strange.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you necessarily want to stay with iepngfix.htc? Have you looked at [jquery.pngFix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/)? It hasn't been updated in a while, but I don't think a lot of these png fixes have.

As a direct answer to your question, I don't know how to fix it. What kind of error are you getting? Is there an error or is it just not working?